# SQL IF statement without ELSE | THEN

Tags: sql, presto

I'm reviewing some code and I've observed the following syntax:

```sql
...
IF (
    (ds > date_of_interest)
    1,
    0
   )
```

The full query is very long and beyond the scope of this question. But the snippet above adequately illustrates my question. I'm curious, are `ELSE` or `THEN` statements not required by SQL? This code block seems to mean that if a given date stamp, ds, is greater than a date of interest, return 1 else 0.

Is this correct? And if so, when are `ELSE` and `THEN` statements absolutely necessary?

Comment: `else/then` are not required

Comment: You don't say what RDBMS you are using but that just looks like a function called `IF` that accepts three parameters, `predicate`, `result if true`, `result if false`.

Comment: An ANSI Standard SQL version of that IF function would be `CASE WHEN ds > date_of_interest THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. It can only return one value, it's not flow control.

Comment: @LukStorms, if the IF statement was evaluated to be false, it would return 0, yeah? What do you mean would not be possible, when you say it's not flow control?

Comment: In MS SQL Server :  ```IIF((ds > date_of_interest), 1, 0)```

Comment: " if the IF statement was evaluated to be false, it would return 0?" - if it was evaluated to be `false` or `unknown` probably. SQL uses three valued logic. So earlier I should have said `result if else` for the third parameter

Comment: As a function it's not exactly SQL per se.

Comment: tag with db platform, please

Comment: @jbuddy_13 With flow control I mean [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow). It's what you do in an imperative programming language like f.e. C.  But pure SQL is a [declarative programming language](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming).  Although, most RDBMS also support languages like T-Sql, PL/SQL that can be used in functions/procedures.

Comment: I don't use Presto but from a quick look at its documentation it doesn't seem to support any procedural `IF` at all. A procedural `IF` would allow you to do something like `IF <condition> SELECT a,b FROM Foo ELSE  SELECT c,d,e FROM Bar` - but I don't see any sign Presto supports that so you only have the `IF` function I think

Answer (score 3):

Presto supports next [IF](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#if) functions:

- `if(condition, true_value)` - Evaluates and returns `true_value` if condition is `true`, otherwise `null` is returned and `true_value` is not evaluated.
- `if(condition, true_value, false_value)` - Evaluates and returns `true_value` if condition is `true`, otherwise evaluates and returns `false_value`.

So the do not have else/then statements.

And, as docs state `if` functions are language constructs which are equivalent to the `CASE` expression, which has then/else:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN condition THEN true_value
    [ ELSE false_value ]
END
```